# How do I pass a variable from one method to another within the same class in Dart?

Tags: class, dart, oop, methods, scope

I am trying to pass the "l" variable from the **purchase** method to **greet** method within the same **"Customer"** class. How can I do this?
I have tried in many ways but couldn't get the right answer/syntax. Didn't find any youtube video/previously asked stack overflow questions on this.
I am new to Dart OOP and would be really grateful if someone could help me out with this.

```
class Customer{
  String? name;
  int? l;

  Customer(String? name){
    this.name = name;
    this.l = l;
  }

  void purchase(List<String> args){
    int l = args.length;
    this.l = l;
    for(int i = 0;i<l;i++){
      print(args[i]);
    }
  }

  void greet([name = 'none']){
    if(name != 'none'){
      print('Hello $name');
      print('$name, you purchased ${this.l} item(s)');
    }
    else{
      print('Hello!');
      print('${this.name}, you purchased ${this.l} item(s)');
      }
  }



}

void main(){

Customer customer_1 = Customer("Sam");
customer_1.greet();
customer_1.purchase(["chips", "chocolate", "orange juice"]);
print("-----------------------------");
Customer customer_2 = Customer("David");
customer_2.greet("David");
customer_2.purchase(["orange juice"]);

}
```

***Output***

```
Hello!
Sam, you purchased null item(s)
chips
chocolate
orange juice
-----------------------------
Hello David
David, you purchased null item(s)
orange juice
```

***Expected output***

```
Hello!
Sam, you purchased 3 item(s)
chips
chocolate
orange juice
-----------------------------
Hello David!
David, you purchased 1 item(s)
orange juice
```

Comment: call `purchase` on your customer before calling `greet`.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually thinking wrong, the item number printing could be done inside the **purchase** method.

```
class Customer{
  String name;
  int l;

  Customer(String name){
    this.name = name;
    this.l = l;
  }


  void greet([name = 'none']){
    if(name != 'none'){
      this.name =name;
      print('Hello ${this.name}');
    }
    else{
      print('Hello!');
      }
  }

  void purchase(List<String> args){
    int l = args.length;
    this.l = l;
    for(int i = 0;i<l;i++){
      print(args[i]);
    }
  print('${this.name}, you purchased ${this.l} item(s)');

  }
}
```

***Output***

```
Hello!
Sam, you purchased 3 item(s)
chips
chocolate
orange juice
-----------------------------
Hello David!
David, you purchased 1 item(s)
orange juice
```